# SQL script to XML format

Tags: java, sql, xml, parsing, converters

one major requirement in my java application is to store sql queries on databases to be used later on.
Since my application connects to different database types like MSSQL, HSQL, Oracle ... etc, and since each type has its own sql script format, I need a parser/converter to parse my sql script to one uniform language (XML) and the other way around.

so when storing a script like 'SELECT * FROM [Project].[dbo].tableName' (MSSQL) it would be parsed to lets say:

```
<Select>
<fields>*</fields>
<tableSource>tableName</tableSource>
```

My question is that is there a present free downloadable converter to be used for this task which supports different types of DB syntax, or if not which is the most efficient way to implement this parser to be able to cover most of the syntax.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) and for instance [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) for an implementation thereof. - Using hibernate you have, among others, the possibility to use the Hibernate Query Language (HQL), which Hibernate will then translate at runtime to the corresponding SQL statements for the DBMS used. - Or maybe just have a look at Hibernate's [SQL Dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html).

Comment: @HannoBinder will research it and let you know. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

What about use this structure

```
<sqls>
<sql>
<db-type name="mysql" />
<sql-query><[CDTATA[select * form .....]]></sql-query>
</sql>
<sql>
<db-type name="oracle" />
<sql-query><[CDTATA[select * form .....]]></sql-query>
</sql>
<sqls>
```

Comment: not sure if its the most efficient solution. 
you want me to generate the appropriate query for each type of db I deal with. So each time I decide to add a new db system, I need to update older XMLs with new db-type, which is size limiting (consider a large query that has aliasing, joins, functions ... etc)